# Why is there gap above images?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this:
[image]

I have achieved this:

[image]

I don't understand why is there gap above the button images? The page is live at http://shrineweb.in/other-files/clients/omypet/tellerest/index.html

Markup:

```
<section id="banner">
<nav> <a href="#"><img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_09.png" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_10.png" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_11.png" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_12.png" alt=""></a>
</nav>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#banner { width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}
#banner nav { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#banner nav img { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your header is giving that space, it's larger than it's visible content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424087/why-is-there-gap-before-my-unordered-list
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467782/why-is-there-gap-above-the-form

Comment: I think, you can adjust margin.Please provide plunker/fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your header css and add same height as your image like this

```
header { width: 950px; height: 56px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is created by the logo image. Images are inline elements so they have a white-space after them. To remove the white-space, you can display the image as a block element by adding this CSS :

```
header > img{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a float issue please add this code

```
header img {
    display: block ;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in my firebug  @laksh

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these to prevent this:

```
header img {display: block;}

header img {vertical-align:top;}
```

The gap is caused by the image's default `vertical-align: baseline`, which aligns it with the baseline of any text it might sit beside.